# php substr() and currency symbol strange output

Tags: php, laravel, string, split

This is a little bit rude code and I am having this output for this simple string formatting sample.

```
foreach (Transaction::where('customer',$id)->cursor() as $ftr) {
               
               $origValue=$ftr->value;
               $currency= mb_substr($origValue, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
               $value = substr($origValue, 1);

               dd($value);    //
}
```

> $originalValue is equal for example to "$50.00";

> $currency is setted correctly to "$";

$value should be "50.00" but this is the result of the above dd() is:

> b"£50.00"

($originalValue is still the same even after the "mb_substr" operation)

what I have made wrong?

Comment: ps with regex works i know, but this should work!

Comment: I think you should dd your other variables as well, just to be sure.
What do you get with `dd($origValue, $currency, $value);` ?

Comment: The value variable return the right value (50.00). What the "dd" function does?

Comment: dd (dump and die) .. try strval( $origValue)

Comment: im at deploy stage, and im getting result trough artisan command, but unitl now no problem on debug with dd(); i fixed for now with regex, but this thing drive me crazy

Comment: `b"` means there's an encoding issue. Maybe your encoding is not actually UTF 8, try an [`mb_detect_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to check what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem.

You are trying to return the part of string using substr where your string `$origValue` has a special characters. So look at the code below

```
echo substr("£50.00", 1); // will print �50.00
echo mb_substr("£50.00", 1 , 5); // will print 50.00
```

Also read through this
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.func-overload

Comment: ok now assume to have sense, but ive tried even to santize input from special char, but i didn extract the number value... so this couldnt be my path...i dont know the lenght of a string before and i dont want use all the time strr_len, so the problem is all about special char, give thanks

Comment: Yep, there is only one way to use this if you want to achieve your goal. `mb_substr("£50.00",1,mb_strlen("£50.00"));`